# Locate elements inside Shadow-root using Protractor

Tags: protractor, shadow-dom

Most of my application's elements are under shadow-root(open). I need to automate them using Protractor framework. deepCSS didnt work out.  Please help me with automating these elements - mostly click.

I have to click on shadow-root elements using my protractor automation framework.  I tried deepCSS, xpath etc. nothing worked.

```
    var spanElem = element.all(by.deepCss('.heading'));
    spanElem.click()
            //browser.actions().mouseMove(spanElem).click().perform();
```

Comment: First of all: what's the error you get? Second: Can you provide HTML source of the page. And last but not least: `spanElem` is `ElementArrayFinder` - you can not perform `click` method on it. See the reference (available only for `ElementFincer`): https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.click

Answer (score 0):

Similar questions:

- [deepCss is failing to identify an element inside the shadow root in Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319508/deepcss-is-failing-to-identify-an-element-inside-the-shadow-root-in-protractor)
- [Protractor: Unable select input element inside a shadow DOM (Polymer) using by.deepCss('input')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402888/protractor-unable-select-input-element-inside-a-shadow-dom-polymer-using-by-d)

It seems Shadow DOM is not yet well supported by protractor. The Second question has an answer pointing to this issue https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4367 and a workaround for adding a custom locator `by.addLocator('css_sr', (cssSelector: string, opt_parentElement, ....`. I confirm this works in my case too.