# No element found using locator error after switching to iframe using protractor

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have been trying to download embedded PDF from webpage using protractor selenium. I'm currently stuck on having to actually download the file since I always got the following error:

> - Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="download"])

It cannot find the button even after switching to frame.

I have also tried the approach indicated in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56986848/how-to-download-embedded-pdf-from-webpage-using-selenium) where it extracts the src attribute value and go directly to the URL but same issue. The download button (icon) cannot be found.

We have the same exact requirements where we just need to click the download icon embedded in the PDF which happens to be inside an iframe. Example page like [this](https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/1085).

Here is my code snippet.

```
        const iframe = $('#printFrame'),            
              downloadBtn = $('#download'),
              content = $('#content');

        await this.disableWaitForAngular();
        await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(iframe),waitTimeout);
        console.log("Switching to iframe...");
        await browser.switchTo().frame(iframe.getWebElement());

        await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(content), waitTimeout);
        await browser.actions().mouseMove(content).perform();

        console.log("Waiting for download button.");
        await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(downloadBtn), waitTimeout);

        await downloadBtn.click();

        await browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
        await this.enableWaitForAngular();
```

**UPDATE:**

Tried to inject the following code as suggested on one of the proposed answers before and after switching frames but it gives me an error.

```
const downloadIcon: WebElement = await browser.executeScript('return document.querySelector("#viewer").shadowRoot.querySelector("#toolbar").shadowRoot.querySelector("#downloads").shadowRoot.querySelector("#download").shadowRoot.querySelector("#icon > iron-icon");');

    await downloadIcon.click();
```

Error:

```
 - Failed: javascript error: Cannot read property 'shadowRoot' of null
(Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.66)
(Driver info: chromedriver=87.0.4280.20 (c99e81631faa0b2a448e658c0dbd8311fb04ddbd-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#355}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

Download icon for reference:
[image]

Comment: Not sure is it going to help but try to get frem like:
browser.switchTo().frame(1)

Comment: I actually have tried that, and errors. Cannot find the frame.

Comment: To download an embedded PDF with Chrome, launch the browser with preference `'plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": true`, switch to the frame `iframe[src$=pdf]` and click on `#open-button`.

Answer (score 3):

On the [example page](https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/1085) you provided, there is no "Download" button, because this button is a part of the Browser, not the page. You can't find it with any type of selector.

But we have `pdf` loaded there as an `iframe`, so we can create our own download button:

```js
a = document.createElement('a'); a.href = $('iframe').src; a.download = "hello.pdf"; a.click();
```

So copy this code, go to [your page](https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/1085), paste it into console and run. This will download the file.

This is just and example, but maybe you can adjust this idea to your needs.

**UPDATE**

Ok, I will try to explain what is under the hood. Here are the **same** [page](https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/1085) in different browsers: Chrome, FF, Edge, IE.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the "inner contents" of PDF page are different, because it is not a page-ralative, it is controlled by the browser and it's plugins.

Pressing the "download" icon/button is the same as pressing something inside the plugin. It is not possible.

Actually, the page itself has only PDF object inside, not the controls.

For example in IE you can not locate "download" button. It simply does not exist, but we can press on it ("in browser", not "in page"), look:

[image]

Comment: The download button will be visible upon mouse hover. Please see description for the picture. It is actually a download icon, not "Download" button. Thanks!

Comment: @Harvey ok, I added description and images to my answer. Please take a look.

Comment: I now got your point. Thank you very much for the explanation. I appreciate it.
I have tried pasting the js code you gave to the console, and it really did work. Will try to imitate this using typescript. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think that the issue you have is due to shadow-root.

1. Try to use `by.deepCss(selector)` Protractor method. If this is not working, look at the workaround [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4367).
2. You can get the [src](https://www.w3docs.com/uploads/media/default/0001/01/540cb75550adf33f281f29132dddd14fded85bfc.pdf) attribute of the iframe and open it in a new window. Then sendKeys Ctrl+S.
3. You can try to run as JavaScript code in protractor:

   `document.querySelector("#viewer").shadowRoot.querySelector("#toolbar").shadowRoot.querySelector("#downloads").shadowRoot.querySelector("#download").shadowRoot.querySelector("#icon > iron-icon").click();`

I get this while inspecting the element and selected "Copy JS Path" from Chrome DevTools.

Reference:
[How to interact with the elements within #shadow-root (open) while Clearing Browsing Data of Chrome Browser using cssSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-interact-with-the-elements-within-shadow-root-open-while-clearing-brow)
[deepCss is failing to identify an element inside the shadow root in Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319508/deepcss-is-failing-to-identify-an-element-inside-the-shadow-root-in-protractor)
[Protractor: Unable select input element inside a shadow DOM (Polymer) using by.deepCss('input')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402888/protractor-unable-select-input-element-inside-a-shadow-dom-polymer-using-by-d)
https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.deepCss
https://superuser.com/questions/505899/keyboard-shortcuts-for-chrome-pdf-viewer

Comment: This is the first time I have encountered this term. So I really thought this would solve my issue. I've tried injecting in my code what you have suggested, the value of the JS Path. But then I have encountered this error.

 Failed: javascript error: Cannot read property 'shadowRoot' of null.

Also tried to switch to iframe first but no luck.

Comment: You can try deepCss protractor method https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.deepCss.

Comment: I tried another appoarch that looks promising - open in new window the source from the iframe https://www.w3docs.com/uploads/media/default/0001/01/540cb75550adf33f281f29132dddd14fded85bfc.pdf
Then sendKeys Ctrl+S in order to download it. I will add my two suggestions to my answer.

Comment: Tried your 2nd suggestion which is much easier to implement. But I'm not sure what element to sendkeys, so I tried to send using the body.   

await element(by.css('body')).sendKeys(Key.chord(Key.CONTROL, 's'));

No luck. So will try the first suggestion, with the shadowroot workaround. Thank you very much. Appreciate the help. Will update you.

Comment: I also tried the non-element variant:     browser.actions().keyDown(Key.CONTROL).sendKeys('s').keyUp(Key.CONTROL).perform();

Comment: Not sure if this would trigger the download so I've added chrome capabilities in config.       

plugins:{
   always_open_pdf_externally: true
  }

Answer (score 0):

in protractor its anti-pattern to mix chaining and awaiting together:

```
isPDFDownloadSuccessful: () => Promise<boolean> = async() => {        
        await this.disableWaitForAngular(); //function equivalent to browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        const iframe = await element(by.tagName("iframe"));
        console.log("Switching to iFrame...");        
        await browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.tagName('iframe')).getWebElement());
        await element(by.id("download")).click()
     
        //Insert here actions to check successful download 
        return true;    
    };
```

Comment: Understood. I am used to doing this. I've just tried to chain because I thought that that's causing the issue which is not in my case. btw, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code did the work

```
await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
await browser.get('https://www.sebi.gov.in/enforcement/orders/jun-2019/adjudication-order-in-respect-of-three-entities-in-the-matter-of-prism-medico-and-pharmacy-ltd-_43323.html');
let $iFrame = $('iframe[src*="sebi"]'),
    $downloadButton = $('#download');
await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf($iFrame), 5000);
await browser.switchTo().frame($iFrame.getWebElement());
await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf($downloadButton), 2000);
await $downloadButton.click();
await browser.sleep(2500);
await browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
```

if it doesn't work, then there might be something wrong with your config, so you'll need to update your question and include its content

Comment: probably you just needed to wait for content to load

Comment: Okay will try to have some added waits. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently, upon checking the sample I gave is not the closest. Here's the closest example page that I'm working with.

http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf

I have tried almost the same exact code that you have see my updates in my question.

Comment: I have added a mouseMove action to mimic the hover action for the download icon to be visible. But still no luck.

Comment: 1. I already spent time and solved the task given in the question. for another problem please open another question. 2. the url you added just opens the pdf, what does it have to do with iframes and the problem you were describing?

Comment: 1. Okay will do. 
2. This should be the URL. >>
https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/1085