# Handling multiple shadow element in cypress

Tags: cypress

I am try to automation a screen that has multiple shadow elements. For example, I have to set data for a text field called 'Student Name'. This field has to traverse through multiple shadow elements.

```
cy.get('app-screen)
.shadow()
.find('app-toolbar')
.shadow()
.find('student-container')
.shadow()
.find('input[id="studentName"]')
.type("Viola");
```

Is there an alternative where I can specify like this:

```
cy.get('app-screen app-toolbar student-container input[id="studentName"]').type('Viola');
```

I came through a solution for similar one for protractor. Is there a solution available for Cypress like adding customer locator?
[Protractor: Unable select input element inside a shadow DOM (Polymer) using by.deepCss('input')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402888/protractor-unable-select-input-element-inside-a-shadow-dom-polymer-using-by-d)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `cypress.json` and write. This makes sure that all your get and find queries automatically go through shadow dom's without explicitly mentioning it.

```js
includeShadowDom: true
```

And then in your test write:

```js
cy.get('app-screen).find('input[id="studentName"]').type("Viola")
```

Comment: Hi, I updated 'cypress.json' as you suggested and this works fine. But, I want the statement to be like this.

cy.get('app-screen input[id="studentName"]').type("Viola");

When I execute this statement, it's saying element not found.

Comment: You can try this. I am not sure if this will work. Assuming the sequence and the nested elements are correct. `cy.get('app-screen > app-toolbar > student-container > input[id="studentName"]).type('voila')`

Comment: Yes, I tried this. The sequence of the nested elements are correct. I checked that using JavaScript query selector in console of the chrome browser. But, the step fails while running through cypress, stating element never found.

Comment: Yes thats what I thought. Then I guess using `get` and `find` is the only way i could think of to work for this use case.

Comment: Hi, is there any other option to write all nested shadow elements under 'get' and without setting 'includeShadowDom: true' in cypress.json?